# For loop, integer value is not updating

Tags: java, for-loop

The value for salary is not updating in the `for` loop. If I enter the salary is 17000, then % for the first year is 5% I get the output of 17850 which is correct. Then loop goes back again and I input for example 5% again, I get output of 17850 again. I expected it to add another 5% to get 18742.5.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of employees"));    
int yr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of years"));

for (int i = 1; i <=n; i ++) {
   double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the salary for employee "+i));
   for (int y = 1; y <= yr; y++) {
      double percentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the percentage for year " +y));
      double perc =(salary * percentage / 100);
      double ann = perc + salary;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Annual salary for employee " +i +" for the year " +y +" is €"+ann);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Should you not store your variable `ann` back into the salary as that will be their new salary, at the end of the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are not updating the salary each year, so the results will be the same every year. Try updating the salary each year or save the salary in a different variable.

Here's a modification to your code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of employees"));    
int yr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of years"));

for (int i = 1; i <=n; i ++) {
   double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the salary for employee "+i));
   for (int y = 1; y <= yr; y++) {
      double percentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the percentage for year " +y));
      double perc =(salary * percentage / 100);
      salary = perc + salary;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Annual salary for employee " +i +" for the year " +y +" is €"+salary);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I can see my mistake now :)

Comment: @PatrykMichta glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

Your `salary` is not updated because is never used in any kind of accumulator...

you defined here:

```
double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the salary for employee "+i));
```

and after that you are reading it but never writing over it..

Answer (score 0):

Little modification in your code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of employees"));    
int yr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of years"));

for (int i = 1; i <=n; i ++) {
   double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the salary for employee "+i));
   for (int y = 1; y <= yr; y++) {
      double percentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the percentage for year " +y));
      double perc =(salary * percentage / 100);
      double ann = perc + salary;
      salary = ann;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Annual salary for employee " +i +" for the year " +y +" is €"+ann);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
salary=ann;
```

After:

```
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Annual salary for employee " +i +" for the year " +y +" is €"+ann);
```

Modified Code:

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of employees"));    
int yr = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the amount of years"));

for (int i = 1; i <=n; i ++) {
   double salary = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the salary for employee "+i));
   for (int y = 1; y <= yr; y++) {
      double percentage = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the percentage for year " +y));
      double perc =(salary * percentage / 100);
      double ann = perc + salary;
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Annual salary for employee " +i +" for the year " +y +" is €"+ann);
      salary=ann;
   } 
}
```

Hope this get your solution.